# Error opening a txt file in Android - File not found

Tags: android, filenotfoundexception

In the ModificaTessera activity I save some data in a txt file and it works well.
In MainActivity I have to read this data but I can't because every time I try to open the txt file I got this error:

java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/data/appname/files/data.txt: open failed: ENOENT (no such file or directory)

This is the code I use to open and read the file:

**MainActivity.java**

```
try
{

     InputStream inputPosizione = openFileInput("PosizioniTessereUtente.txt");
     InputStream inputCodici = openFileInput("CodiciTessereUtente.txt");


    if(inputPosizione != null)
    {
        InputStreamReader streamPosizione = new InputStreamReader(inputPosizione);
        InputStreamReader streamCodici = new InputStreamReader(inputCodici);

        BufferedReader bufferPosizione = new BufferedReader(streamPosizione);
        BufferedReader bufferCodici = new BufferedReader(streamCodici);

        Integer pos = null;
        String cod = null;
        while((pos = Integer.parseInt(bufferPosizione.readLine())) != null)
        {

            cod = bufferCodici.readLine();
            Tessera tmp = new Tessera(negozi.tessereDefault.get(pos).getNome(),
                    negozi.tessereDefault.get(pos).getLogo());
            tmp.setCodice(cod);

            tessereUtente.add(tmp);
        }
        bufferPosizione.close();
        bufferCodici.close();
    }
}
catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Here, I write in TXT file

**ModificaTessera.java**

```
OutputStreamWriter out;
try {

out = new OutputStreamWriter(openFileOutput("PosizioneTessereUtente.txt", MODE_APPEND));

String pos = Integer.toString(posizione);
Log.v("posizione",pos);
out.write(pos);
out.write('\n');
out.close();

Log.v("codice",codice);
out = new OutputStreamWriter(openFileOutput("CodiciTessereUtente.txt", MODE_APPEND));
out.write(codice);
out.write('\n');
out.close();

} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
// TODO Auto-generated catch block
e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
// TODO Auto-generated catch block
e.printStackTrace();
}
```

and this is the LogCat error:

```
01-21 19:19:29.529: W/System.err(31592): java.io.FileNotFoundException:
/data/data/com.activity.cardsnuovo/files/PosizioniTessereUtente.txt: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
01-21 19:19:29.529: W/System.err(31592): at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:456)
01-21 19:19:29.529: W/System.err(31592): at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:76)
01-21 19:19:29.529: W/System.err(31592): at android.app.ContextImpl.openFileInput(ContextImpl.java:955)
01-21 19:19:29.529: W/System.err(31592): at android.content.ContextWrapper.openFileInput(ContextWrapper.java:175)
01-21 19:19:29.530: W/System.err(31592): at com.activity.cardsnuovo.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:91)
01-21 19:19:29.530: W/System.err(31592): at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5933)
01-21 19:19:29.530: W/System.err(31592): at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
01-21 19:19:29.530: W/System.err(31592): at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2251)
01-21 19:19:29.530: W/System.err(31592): at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
01-21 19:19:29.530: W/System.err(31592): at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
01-21 19:19:29.530: W/System.err(31592): at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
01-21 19:19:29.530: W/System.err(31592): at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
01-21 19:19:29.530: W/System.err(31592): at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
01-21 19:19:29.530: W/System.err(31592): at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
01-21 19:19:29.530: W/System.err(31592): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
01-21 19:19:29.530: W/System.err(31592): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
01-21 19:19:29.530: W/System.err(31592): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:89)
01-21 19:19:29.530: W/System.err(31592): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
01-21 19:19:29.530: W/System.err(31592): Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
01-21 19:19:29.530: W/System.err(31592): at libcore.io.Posix.open(Native Method)
01-21 19:19:29.530: W/System.err(31592): at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.open(BlockGuardOs.java:186)
01-21 19:19:29.530: W/System.err(31592): at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:442)
01-21 19:19:29.530: W/System.err(31592): ... 17 more
01-21 19:19:29.541: D/OpenGLRenderer(31592): Render dirty regions requested: true
01-21 19:19:29.547: D/Atlas(31592): Validating map...
01-21 19:19:29.572: I/Adreno-EGL(31592): <qeglDrvAPI_eglInitialize:410>: QUALCOMM Build: 10/24/14, 167c270, I68fa98814b
01-21 19:19:29.572: I/OpenGLRenderer(31592): Initialized EGL, version 1.4
01-21 19:19:29.585: D/OpenGLRenderer(31592): Enabling debug mode 0
01-21 19:19:29.662: V/RenderScript(31592): Application requested CPU execution
01-21 19:19:29.666: V/RenderScript(31592): 0xa240c400 Launching thread(s), CPUs 4
```

Comment: The example you provided (data.txt) has nothing to do with the posted code. Post the snippet where your code throws an `Exception`, post your `LogCat` logs and point the exact line where it crashes.

Comment: I have added the LogCat error.

Comment: Where's the evidence that this file has indeed been created? You should post the code where you write into the file. Also you should open up the path on your device and check whether the file actually exists or not.

Answer (score 1):

I think the file name is different. You have made a mistake with the spelling. That's the reason.

```
out = new OutputStreamWriter(openFileOutput("PosizioneTessereUtente.txt", MODE_APPEND));
```

here the file name is **PosizioneTessereUtente.txt**

But here

```
InputStream inputPosizione = openFileInput("PosizioniTessereUtente.txt");
```

it is **PosizioniTessereUtente.txt**

Comment: did u try installing the project fresh? and also a project->clean? Try this and let me know if u still face the problem

Comment: Before, the intent from ModificaTessera to MainActivity worked, now it crashes and I don't know there reasone

Comment: can you tell me the exception that you get now? its a different one right?

Comment: It's the same, java.io.FileNotFoundException,  open failed: ENOENT